# how to read first N records using hive?

Tags: sql, hiveql

```
select row_number() over() as rownum1,* from emp where rownum1 in 
(select row_number() over() as rownum from emp<= select count(*)/2 from emp);
```

i want read first N records from hive table using HQL

Comment: add "limit N" to the end of sql

Answer (score 1):

To get top 5 records, use format with `limit` keyword :

```
select *
from
(
 select row_number() over() as rownum1,* from emp where rownum1 in 
(select row_number() over() as rownum from emp<= select count(*)/2 from emp)
)
order by rownum1 limit 5
```

or restrict set with `<`

```
select *
from
(
 select row_number() over() as rownum1,* from emp where rownum1 in 
(select row_number() over() as rownum from emp<= select count(*)/2 from emp)
)
where rownum1 <= 5
order by rownum1
```